# Link between mean and median

Tags: statistics

While doing some experiments today, I ran into the following:
$$\mu=m+d$$

where $\mu$ is the arithmetic mean of a set of $N$ values $X=\left\{ x_{i}\right\} $,
$m$ is the median of $X$ and $d$ is the median of the distance
to the median, i.e.:
$$d=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left|x_{i}-m\right|$$

I am sure this must be a well known result, but I could not find it
on the internet. If you know this, can you please send me a link?

At the same time, I have tried to demonstrate it, but could not go
further than this, assuming that $N$ is odd, that $X$ is sorted
in ascending order, and that the index of $m$ in the sorted dataset
is $M=\frac{N+1}{2}$: 
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
m+d & = & m+\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left|x_{i}-m\right|\\
 & = & m+\frac{1}{N}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{M-1}\left|x_{i}-m\right|+x_{M}-m+\sum_{i=M+1}^{N}\left|x_{i}-m\right|\right]
\end{array}$$

We know by definition that:

- $x_{M}=m$, so $x_{M}-m=0$
- in the sorted dataset, $\forall i=1...M-1,\, x_{i}\leq m$ and $\forall i=M+1...N,\, x_{i}>m$

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
m+d & = & m+\frac{1}{N}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{M-1}\left|x_{i}-m\right|+x_{M}-m+\sum_{i=M+1}^{N}\left|x_{i}-m\right|\right]\\
 & = & m+\frac{1}{N}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{M-1}\left(m-x_{i}\right)+\sum_{i=M+1}^{N}\left(x_{i}-m\right)\right]\\
 & = & m+\frac{1}{N}\left[\left(M-1\right)m-\sum_{i=1}^{M-1}x_{i}+\sum_{i=M+1}^{N}x_{i}-\left(N-M\right)m\right]
\end{array}$$

By definition of the median, we know that there are the same number
of data on both sides of $m$. This result is confirmed by the fact
that , with $M=\frac{N+1}{2}$, $M-1=N-M=\frac{N-1}{2}$.
So:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
m+d & = & m+\frac{1}{N}\left[\left(M-2\right)m-\sum_{i=1}^{M-1}x_{i}+\sum_{i=M+1}^{N}x_{i}-\left(N-M-1\right)m\right]\\
 & = & m+\frac{1}{N}\left[\sum_{i=M+1}^{N}x_{i}-\sum_{i=1}^{M-1}x_{i}\right]
\end{array}$$

But I can not go further...Anyone to help me ? Thanks !

Comment: Your formula cannot possibly be right as one can easily provide examples of distributions where median is less than the mean (e.g., Bernoulli with $p=0.6$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
X = \{1,2,3,4,10000\}
$$
$$
m = 3\quad \mu = 2002\quad d = 2000.2
$$

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my formula, I was calculating $$d=\frac{1}{N}\sum\left(x_{i}-m\right)$$ (without the absolute value). And in this case, $d+m$ obviously equals $\mu$. Thanks for your answer, it made me realise my mistake.

Comment: @GillesM No pb, actually I don't know if that changed anything in your proof, but if you can conclude I'd be interested to read it if you want to edit your OP.

Comment: Then the prof becomes:
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
m+d & = & m+\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(x_{i}-m\right)\\
 & = & m+\frac{1}{N}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_{i}-Nm\right]\\
 & = & m-m+\mu\\
 & = & \mu
\end{array}
$$

Was it actually your question ?

Comment: @GillesM :) Yes, I didn't try to do it actually, but it's obvious as you showed.